# Can you run history within a Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

*Makefiles have been around for a while, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate!*

I've been using Makefiles to bundle bash operations with lots of flags or arguments (not their original purpose, I know)

**Is it possible to implement the following `history` command in a Makefile?**

```bash
history | tail -n 100 | cut -c 8- | sort | uniq
```

`Makefile`

```makefile
#* Setup
.PHONY: $(shell sed -n -e '/^$$/ { n ; /^[^ .\#][^ ]*:/ { s/:.*$$// ; p ; } ; }' $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

help: ## list make commands
    @echo ${MAKEFILE_LIST}
    @awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "} /^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## / {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

#* Commands
get-history: ## custom history lookup command
    @history | tail -n 100 | cut -c 8- | sort | uniq

HIS ?= ${history}
test: ## test
    echo ${HIS}
```

^this obviously didn't work so any tips or doc links would be appreciated

Comment: Since `history` is a bash mechanism, present in **interactive** bash only, you have to create a child process of an interactive bash to make it work. Now it depends on how you configure your interactive bash: If you have it start with a fresh history, you can't do it obviously. If you have it load the history from a history-save-file, it could work. I don't see the point in doing this. You could alternatively collect the history into a file **before** starting _make_, and use this file from inside your Makefile.

Comment: Small correction: You don't need an interactive bash. You can also use a non-interactive one, and turn on the history mechanism by `set -o history`. Having said this, I don't see in your makefile that you would use _bash_ at all. Did you set the shell for _make_ to _bash_?

Comment: Indeed, this seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you want to summarize the commands from the currently running shell, why use `make`? If you only care about the saved history from some earlier sessions, perhaps manipulate `$HOME/.bash_history` directly?

Comment: ah, interesting. I wasn't aware of the [interactive/non-interactive](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) distinction so this is helpful. reading more now...

Comment: So my assumption was that any command line binary could be utilized within a `Makefile` but it sounds like certain bash operations aren't automatically available to make. @tripleee is correct, I'm not sure I fully understood the question I was asking. Nonetheless both responses were helpful -- happy to upvote/accept if posted as a response

Comment: @user1934428 Please go ahead

Comment: @tripleee: Do me a favour and check my answer - maybe I missed something.

Comment: The thing that was alluded to above and is maybe not completely clear, is that `make` _doesn't_ invoke `bash` as it's shell.  By default, it invokes `sh` (POSIX standard shell).  This may be `bash`, or it may be some other shell, but you can only rely on it supporting POSIX standard functions.  Any bash-specific functions, like history, are likely not available.  If you want make to invoke bash, you need to force it with `SHELL = /bin/bash`.  The answer below doesn't need this because it's just invoking a shell script, not running commands directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you Makefile is run from an interactive bash, and that you want to access the history of this interactive shell from within the Makefile, I would approach it as follows:

As a setup, I would ensure that your interactive bash has its own history file, so that it does not get mixed up with the history of bash processes in other terminals.

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.hi.$$
export HISTFILE_TO_USE=$HISTFILE
```

In practice, you would put these three lines into a shell function defined in your .bashrc, so that you can type it with a single command every time you need it.

From now on, commands in your shell will be added to your $HISTFILE. Right before `make` is invoked, you do a

```
history -a
```

which appends the history to your history file. Perhaps the best would be do create in your .bashrc a function wrapper or an alias for `make`, so that you don't have to do this manually everytime:

```
makhi() {
  history -a
  make "$@"
}
```

Now the problem of how to pick up the history inside a bash script; this includes the use in your makefile, since you can always run scripts from the makefile.

IMO, it should work like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
PARENT_HISTFILE=${HISTFILE_TO_USE:-$HOME/.bash_history}
set -o history # turn on history
shopt -s histappend # Ensure that the history file is not overwritten
histfile -r "$PARENT_HISTFILE" # Read saved history into memory
history # should show the saved history
...
```

However, for reason I don't know, this did not work for as documented, in that `histfile -r` did not read the history.

**UPDATE** based on an idea by *tripleee*: The solution works if I make this bash interactive, i.e. have the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/bash -i`, but I still don't understand, why this is necessary in this case. If you follow this route, don't forget that this means that your `.bashrc` will be processed. If this causes trouble, add the option `--norc`.

However, you can alternatively access the history simply with `cat`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
PARENT_HISTFILE=${HISTFILE_TO_USE:-$HOME/.bash_history}
cat "$PARENT_HISTFILE" # shows the saved history
```

Assuming that your script to display the history is named `tailhist` and has executable rights and is in your PATH, you can invoke it from your makefile as

```
get-history:
  @tailhist
```

Actually, for your use case, I could imagine a completely different approach useful. What you are doing is:

1. You have an interactive shell (collecting the history)
2. You run make from the shell
3. You want to display part of your history from make

Since the make process itself is unrelated from your history (i.e. from the viewpoint of `make`, the history is frozen once *make* starts to run), you could equally well run the `history` command before you even enter make. The outcome will be the same. For instance, if you define your function as

```
makhi() {
  export makhi=$(history | tail -n 100 | cut -c 8- | sort | uniq)
  make "$@"
}
```

you just have to print from within *make* the environment variable `makhi`.

Comment: Does the penultimate snippet work if you change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/bash -i`?

Comment: Maybe still explain how to exercise this from `make`, though that part of the use case adds another few degrees of murkiness.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? You have a shell script and you simply run it. The OP already does run external commands (`awk`), so this is not different. What would be more interesting here is, why my first attempt with `history -r` did not work. The only reason why I have inclued a "non-working solution" in an answer, is, that based on the docs it **should** work. I someone can point out my mistake here, I would gladly update the answer, even it's not really relevant for the OP.

Comment: I don't particularly disagree, but that's what the question asks. I'm mainly thinking it would be useful to elaborate on why that requirement is weird and possibly useless.

Comment: @tripleee : It would work indeed, though I don't understand why. Interactivity just sets the history by default, so it should not be necessary. Actually the `-i` could cause problems, if the OP decided to put the "history set-up code" into his .bashrc, which means that  the variable `HISTFILE_TO_USE` would be overwritten. By and large, running a script on purpose as interactive script, causes more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @tripleee : Added the invocation from within _make_ (though I felt a bit silly when doing this), plus added another solution.

Comment: Good update, +1!